# Determining a RAMS capacity, with math. (using ram width, word size etc..)

Tags: math, hardware, ram

Can some one explain the math behind this.

2 RAMS
16-bits wide
16-bit words

32k 16 bit words is the maximum fill up of each.

How do I get the '32k 16-bit words' from the information provided?

Answer (score 1):

While your question was nearly impossible to understand, I'll try to answer anyway:

32768 16-bit words makes 65536 bytes (8 bits per byte)

2^16 = 65536 = The number of bytes that can be addressed using a 16 bit address.